# Why is RenderTargetBitmap.Render so slow?

Tags: wpf

```
var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)view.ActualWidth, (int)view.ActualHeight,
                                 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(view);
```

When I use Render(...), it too slow.

Comment: Slower than what?  Rendering is expensive.  If you want it to go faster, render to a smaller rectangle and use the stretch property.

Comment: This operation have spent about 250 milliseconds, the real-time output image flow to browser. This time too long. How to make Render faster, or have any other ways to bring into the picture quickly Viewport3D it?